# Rails 4 app with Google oauth not loading some pages on heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, google-oauth

It works great locally. Users are able to login using Google or by entering email and password, and are taken to the posts index page which shows all user posts and comments, however, since deploying to Heroku, after clicking "sign in with google", we are taken to that posts index page which shows only the nav bar and none of the ruby after that is firing, and the user is not logged in.

See here: http://surfbuddy.herokuapp.com/ this page looks good, but try the google signin and see what happens

Some details: It is a Rails 4 app, but i'm using the protected_attributes gem, can't figure out if that has something to do with it. I built my own user authentication, and then added the oauth for google. Postgres is running in production, SQLite in dev. I've tried a few things, like the rails_12factor gem, and messing with configs in production.rb.

EDIT: now when I run the server in production I am getting the "we're sorry but something went wrong" and in terminal the error is "FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find table 'users'):"

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more detail, with some of the HTTP headers going back and forth?

The fact that it worked in one place but not another suggests that maybe the redirect_uri is wonky; when you registered your app in developer console, did you include surfbuddy.herokuapps.. in the redirect_uri values?

Comment: At first that was the issue, which was quickly solved by making the redirect_uri in the developer console:  http://surfbuddy.herokuapp.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback Then the page would load, looking the way it does now.

Comment: I've also commented out the before_filter for my authentication on the posts controller to see if that was keeping my code from loading, but that did nothing. I added the word "test" a bunch just to confirm that things will render on that page, which they did, just no 'posts' logic. I'm having a hard time explaining this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Success! After taking apart and rebuilding my authentication and adding some debugging code I was able to see that the request to googles oauth was being received but no user was being returned. For some reason this worked fine in development but would not work in production. The fix was to use oauth 1.0 instead of 2.0. Not sure exactly why 2.0 doesn't work in production.